# Pig latin Java program with try-catch, translation passed though function

Tags: java, function, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I am making a java program that translates a sentence to pig latin. I need to have at least one try-catch in this program and the translation must be done in a function. The original word will be passed to this function and return the translated word back to the function call per my professor's wishes. I am also having trouble asking the user if they want to translate something else. even when I say no it still restarts the program.

this is what I have:

```
package midtermPigLatin;
import java.util.Scanner;

import textio.TextIO;
public class midtermPigLatin {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String yourSentence="";
        boolean again = true;
        try {


        do {
                String[] words;
                System.out.print("Enter your words here: ");
                yourSentence = input.nextLine();
                words = yourSentence.split(" ");
                for (String word : words)
                {
                    if (word.startsWith("a") || word.startsWith("e") || word.startsWith("i") || word.startsWith("o") || word.startsWith("u"))
                        System.out.print(word + "way ");
                    else if (word.startsWith("sh") || word.startsWith("ch") || word.startsWith("th"))
                        System.out.print(word.substring(2)+word.substring(0,2)+"ay ");
                    else
                        System.out.print(word.substring(1)+word.substring(0,1)+"ay ");


                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Do you want to play again, Yes or no");
                again = TextIO.getBoolean();

                } while(!yourSentence.equals("quit"));



            }catch(Exception errMsg)
             {
                System.out.print(" error" + errMsg);
             }

    }
}
```

I just need help modifying my program to pass the translation through a function original word will be passed to this function and return the translated word back to the function call and the ending the program if user says no.

Here is what I get when I run the program:

```
Enter your words here: apple door shave
appleway oorday aveshay 
Do you want to play again, Yes or no
no
Enter your words here:
```